# How can I control YouTube playback using voice commands?

Tags: ios, siri, youtube

I like to listen to music and podcasts on YouTube on my iPhone while driving. I have my own custom playlists containing content to listen to while driving.

One drawback is that there doesn't seem to be a hands-free way of controlling YouTube through Siri. This means that I'm unable to skip forwards or backwards in  playlist while driving without taking my eyes off the road.

I've tried few different Siri commands, including:

- `Play next video`
- `Play previous video`
- `Pause video`
- `Play Bohemian Rhapsody on YouTube`

**How can I control YouTube playback using voice commands?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Siri with this App?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297352/can-i-use-siri-with-this-app)

Answer (score 1):

Try a 3rd party app - perhaps one of those developers coded up their app to include Siri voice commands.

I'm not sure which ones support voice commands; let us know if you find one that does!

Some Youtube alternatives:
[filmora.wondershare.com/.../youtube-app-alternatives.html](https://filmora.wondershare.com/youtube-video-editing/youtube-app-alternatives.html)

Some that allow playing music in the background, might have paid attention to this voice commands feature:
[mashtips.com/youtube-music-streaming-ios-apps/](https://mashtips.com/youtube-music-streaming-ios-apps/)

Comment: Is it even possible to have Siri voice commands outside of Siri in macOS?

Comment: iOS and macOS both have the ability for installed Apps to add custom voice commands/responses as far as I know.  For example, the Wolfram Alpha app on my iPhone added a bunch of results/conversions/calculations that I never used to get before.

Comment: "SiriKit enables your iOS apps and watchOS apps to work with Siri" (https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/). Apple does not mention macOS.